# Large scale word substitutions in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting to perform data cleansing on a field in a large database.  I have a reference table that contains words with their replacements, macros if you like.  I'd like to apply those changes to a table that contains millions of rows, in the most efficient manner possible.  With that said, let me provide some dummy data below so you can visualize the process:

Street_Addresses Table:

```
Street_Name       | Expanded_Name
------------------+--------------
100 Main St Ste 5 | NULL
25 10th Ave Apt 2 | NULL
75 Bridge Rd      | NULL
```

Word_Substitutions Table:

```
Word | Replacement
-----+------------
St   | Street
Ave  | Avenue
Rd   | Road
Ste  | Suite
Apt  | Apartment
```

So the end result would be the following after updates:

```
Street_Name       | Expanded_Name
------------------+--------------
100 Main St Ste 5 | 100 Main Street Suite 5
25 10th Ave Apt 2 | 25 10th Avenue Apartment 2
75 Bridge Rd      | 75 Bridge Road
```

The challenge here is the sheer number of substitutions that need to take place, indeed multiple replacements on a single value.  The intial thought that sprang to mind was to use a scalar function to encapsulate this logic.  But as you can imagine, this is not performant over millions of rows.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION Substitute_Words (@Text varchar(MAX))
RETURNS varchar(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @Text = REPLACE(' ' + @Text + ' ', ' ' + Word + ' ',
    ' ' + Replacement + ' ') FROM Word_Substitutions
    RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@Text))
END
```

I decided to look at a set based operation instead and came up with the following:

```sql
WHILE (1 = 1)
BEGIN
    UPDATE A SET Expanded_Name = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(
    ' ' + ISNULL(A.Expanded_Name, A.Street_Name) + ' ',
    ' ' + W.Word + ' ', ' ' + W.Replacement + ' ')))
    FROM Street_Addresses AS A
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Word, Replacement
    FROM Word_Substitutions WHERE CHARINDEX(' ' + Word + ' ',
    ' ' + ISNULL(A.Expanded_Name, A.Street_Name) + ' ') > 0) AS W

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        BREAK
END
```

Right now, this takes about 2 hours based on my actual dataset and I would like to reduce that if possible - does anyone have suggestions for optimization?

**UPDATE:**

By just using an inner join instead, I was able to reduce the execution time to about 5 minutes.  I had initially thought that using update with an inner join which returns multiple rows would not work.  It appears that the update will still work, but the source row will get a single, not multiple updates.  Apparently SQL Server chooses a random result row for the update, discarding the others.

```sql
WHILE (1 = 1)
BEGIN
    UPDATE A SET Expanded_Name = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(
    ' ' + ISNULL(A.Expanded_Name, A.Street_Name) + ' ',
    ' ' + W.Word + ' ', ' ' + W.Replacement + ' ')))
    FROM Street_Addresses AS A
    INNER JOIN Word_Substitutions AS W ON CHARINDEX(' ' + W.Word + ' ',
    ' ' + ISNULL(A.Expanded_Name, A.Street_Name) + ' ') > 0

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        BREAK
END
```

Comment: How many records are in your word replacement table? 10, 100, 1,000?

Comment: Right now there are about 275 entries.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach here is to have the modified data stored in your database. You can create a separate table with ID and the formatted address or you can rather add additional column in your current table.

Then, because you have already a lot of records, you should update them. Here, I thing you have to options, to create a internal function and use it for update current records (it might be slow, but once it ended you will have the data already in your table) or create [CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) procedure and use the power of regular expressions.

Then for new inserted records, it will be very flexible to create AFTER INSERT [TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) that will call your SQL or CLR function and update the current inserted records.

Comment: Thanks gotqn, I have already looked at using RegEx functions in MDQ, but I think it would still have performance issues calling out to CLR functions.  Your point about storing substitutions and handling incremental updates is valid and something I've been thinking about also.  We have many different sources and determining if a record has changed is problematic.

Comment: Well, I've believe that your issue will be only to UPDATE the records that you have till now. Than using AFTER INSERT TRIGGER and AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER will help to get the modified data in your database every moment.

Answer (score 2):

You could always do something ridiculous and run this as dynamic SQL with all of the replacements inline:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'Street_Name'
select @sql = 'replace(' + @sql + ', '' ' + Word + ' '', '' ' + Replacement + ' '')'
from Word_Substitutions
set @sql = 'update Street_Addresses set Expanded_Name = ' + @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Yes, I totally expect a downvote or two, but this method can work well on occasion given how UDFs and recursive CTEs can sometimes be very slow on large datasets.  And it's fun to post off-the-wall solutions from time to time.

Regardless, I would be curious to see how this would run, especially if combined with the suggestion of storing and trigger-based updating by @gotqn (which I agree with and have upvoted).

I'm currently running about 3 seconds with 275 replacement words and 100k addresses on a modest box.